# jQuery 'enter'-key event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress, onkeypress

I'm having a problem using 'enter'-key as an event to append input from 'form' to a list.
The code below works, but only when I press "cmd+enter" combination, which adds item to my list and opens new tab with the same page.

What I'm willing to achieve is whenever the 'form' field is in focus and I press 'enter'-key (not a 'cmd+enter' combination) the item is added to the list and no new extra tab opens with the same page.
(I'm testing my code in Firefox 48.0 and Safari 9.1.2)

Here's the html part of the code:

```
<form id="inputWindow"> Type-in here: <input type='text' name='input'></input></form>
```

Here's the jQuery part of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#inputWindow').keypress(function(event) {

if (event.which == 13){
var answer = $("input[name=input]").val();
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + answer + '</div>');
   });
});
```

Comment: bind a submit event to the form as enter will trigger implicit submission

Comment: Maybe instead of ranking down the question you could actually help and at least tell me how to do this?

Comment: My comment was meant as a comment. If binding a submit handler solves your problem, then wonderful. if you want to know how to do these things, searching on google and doing your own research will take you a long way. Expecting me to invest my time because you're too lazy to invest your own is *rude* and that sort of behavior is generally not tolerated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's much easier to use .submit instead of .keypress event.
The problem of page reloading is easily solvable by adding onsubmit="return false" to the html part. So the code shall look like this:
html part:

```
<form id="inputWindow" onsubmit="return false"> Type-in here: <input type='text' name='input'></input></form>
```

jQuery part (assuming you have your $(document).ready):

```
$('#inputWindow').submit(function() {
var answer = $("input[name=input]").val();
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + answer + '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some `});` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu62oq3m/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inputWindow').keypress(function(event) {

     if (event.which == 13){
       var answer = $("input[name=input]").val();
        $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + answer + '</div>');
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: I just forgot to paste it, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @thecapnamerica Edit it.

Comment: In my js fiddle the event is fired only when pressing enter without cmd. When i press cmd+enter it doesn't fire up the event